# How to test if objects are overlapping in Android

Tags: android, object, overlapping

I was trying to make a game where a square on the screen is moved up, down, left or right with buttons, and when the square met another randomly placed square, the square would move. However, I don't know how to test if the two ImageViews are overlapping. Please keep answers simple and easy to understand. I am new to android. Here is my code if you need it:

```
package com.example.runaway;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView box = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.player);
    Button pushMedown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.down);



        pushMedown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            int location = (int) box.getY();
            int math = 55;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            location = (int) (math + box.getY()); 
            box.setY(location);
            if (location > 400) {location = location - math;}
            box.setY(location);


        }
    });
                                // up
        final ImageView box1 = box;
        Button pushMeup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);



        pushMeup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 


            int location = (int) box.getY();
            int math = 55;
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        location = (int) (box.getY() - math); 
        box.setY(location);
        if (location < 10) {location = location + math;}
        box.setY(location);

    }
        });

                            // right
            final ImageView box2 = box;
            Button pushMeleft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);



            pushMeleft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 


                int location1 = (int) box.getX();
                int math = 55;
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                location1 = (int) (math + box.getX()); 
                box.setX(location1);
                if (location1 > 400) {location1 = location1 - math;}
                box.setX(location1);

                }
            });
                        // left
            final ImageView box3 = box;
            Button pushMeright = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);



            pushMeright.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 


                    int location1 = (int) box.getX();
                    int math = 55;
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    location1 = (int) (box.getX() - math); 
                    box.setX(location1);
                    if (location1 < 0) {location1 = location1 + math;}
                    box.setX(location1);

                }});                        

        }

private ImageView findByViewId(int imageview1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: remove `private ImageView findByViewId(int imageview1) {`. Don't need this. although it may not solve your other problem

Comment: @Raghunandan Wow, you comment fast, thank you, even if I still have a problem! :3

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ImageViews` are called first and second.

```
if((first.getRight()>second.getLeft()&&first.getLeft()<second.getRight())&&first.getTop()>second.getBottom()&&first.getBottom()<second.getTop())
{
    //the imageViews are overlapping)
}
```